# Delphi REST API Post Sample

Tags: delphi, api, rest, post

Can someone post a simple example of a JSON POST request to an API using Delphi 2005.  I have found numerous examples using GET but the API provider does not allow requests via HTTP GET and does not support URL encoding parameters.

I am brand new to calling REST services (have used SOAP in the past) so please let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would just use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component and call the `Post` method.  Pass the URL as the first argument and your JSON string as the second argument.  Something like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonToSend: TStringList;
  http: TIdHTTP;
begin
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    http.HandleRedirects := True;
    http.ReadTimeout := 5000;
    jsonToSend := TStringList.create;
    try
      jsonToSend.Add('{ Your JSON-encoded request goes here }');
      http.Post('http://your.restapi.url', jsonToSend);
    finally
      jsonToSend.Destroy;
    end;
  finally
    http.Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

I'm assuming you are already able to encode and decode the JSON and that you were just asking how to perform an HTTP post using Delphi.

Comment: ... and will leak memory (http+jsontosend instances) if an exception raised within http.post()...

Answer (score 8):

One option, using some part of our *mORMot* Open Source framework:

```
uses SynCrtSock, SynCommons;
var t: variant;
begin
  TDocVariant.New(t);
  t.name := 'john';
  t.year := 1982;
  TWinHTTP.Post('http://servername/resourcename',t,'Content-Type: application/json');
end;
```

Note that here you can construct your JSON content using a [custom `variant` storage](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/02/25/TDocVariant-custom-variant-type), which will be converted as JSON text when sent to the server.