# How to write a Rest command in Delphi 7 to use REST API from parse.com

Tags: delphi, rest

i hope somebody can help me how to translate the following REST command to delphi 7 to use with Indy idHttp (or other component). I'm using the parse.com plataform, their tutorial generate rest request in CURL and Python, for example:

In Python a POST example:

```
import json,httplib 

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/classes/GameScore', json.dumps({
       "score": 1337,
       "playerName": "Sean Plott",
       "cheatMode": False
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "here-go-application-id",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "here-go-rest-api-key",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

Here the same POST example in CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: here-go-application-id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: here-go-rest-api-key" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

And how GET request in python an curl:

**in python:**

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "here-go-application-id",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "here-go-rest-api-key"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

**in CURL:**

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: here-go-application-id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: here-go-rest-api-key" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm
```

My question is, how can I do the same, but in Delphi 7. I hope my question is clear, because I need this answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743591/delphi-rest-api-post-sample

Answer (score 4):

One option, using some part of our *mORMot* Open Source framework:

```
uses 
   SynCrtSock, // for HTTP process
   SynCommons; // for TDocVariant type support
var t: variant;
begin

  // POST example

  // 1. prepare the JSON content (several ways to do the same)
  t := _Obj(['score',1337,'playerName','Sean Plott','cheatMode',False]);
  // same as:
  t := _Json('"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":False');
  // or with MongoDB extended syntax:
  t := _Json('score:1337,playerName:"Sean Plott",cheatMode:False');
  // or using late-binding to create the object
  TDocVariant.New(t);
  t.score := 1337;
  t.playerName := 'Sean Plott';
  t.cheatMode := false;

  // 2. create the resource on the server
  TWinHTTP.Post(  // or TWinINet.Post(
    'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore',t,
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: here-go-application-id'#13#10+
    'Content-Type: application/json');

  // GET example

  // 1. retrieve the resource
  t := _Json(TWinHTTP.Get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm',
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: here-go-application-id'#13#10+
    'Content-Type: application/json'));

  // 2. access the resource members via late-binding of the variant value
  writeln('score = ',t.score);
  writeln('playerName = ',t.playerName);
  writeln('cheatMode = ',t.cheatMode);
end.
```

It will use either the [WinHTTP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925) or the [WinINet API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331) for the HTTP requests.

And our new [`TDocVariant` custom variant type](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/02/25/TDocVariant-custom-variant-type) for easy JSON process, including late-binding of property names.

Above code is IMHO pretty easy to follow, and will work from Delphi 6 up to XE5. Ensure you retrieve [the latest 1.18 unstable version of our units](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Get+the+source), since `TDocVariant` was just introduced.